# Connect ec2 instance with amazon rds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have made a connection in my php server that on ec2 instance and rds mysql database and it said Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO).

Every time I have try to solve I get a new error.

Comment: can you show some code? (How to you connect)

Comment: this is my connection code 

define ("DB_HOST", "dbinstance.xxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306"); // set database host


define ("DB_USER", "myuser"); // set database user


define ("DB_PASS","mypassword"); // set database password

 mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

 mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS));

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to connect to the RDS endpoint (not 'localhost') and use a password.

Comment: this is my connection code 

define ("DB_HOST", "dbinstance.xxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306"); // set database host


define ("DB_USER", "myuser"); // set database user


define ("DB_PASS","mypassword"); // set database password

 mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

 mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS));

Answer (score 0):

sudo su

apt-get update

apt-get upgrade -y

apt-get dist-upgrade -y

apt-get autoremove -y

apt-get install apache2 php7.0 php7.0-cli php7.0-fpm php7.0-gd php-ssh2 libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-mcrypt mysql-server php7.0-mysql git unzip zip postfix php7.0-curl mailutils php7.0-json phpmyadmin -y
php5enmod mcrypt

vim  /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

--ADD LINE-- 
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

service apache2 restart

nano /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

--ADD LINES BELOW THE PMA CONFIG AREA AND FILL IN DETAILS--

$i++;

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = 'rds endpiont details fill karna hai';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '3306';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysql';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = FALSE;

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'PHPMYADMIN USER NAME FILL KARNA HAI';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'PHPMYADMIN PASSWD  FILL KARNA HAI';